# Negating the fullscreen selector doesn't work

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand, why negating `:fullscreen`, i.e. `:not(:fullscreen)`, does not work as expected.

See https://jsfiddle.net/rmjae4Lc/ for a demo (where it works for `body`, but not for `p`).

```css
:fullscreen button {
  background-color: green;
}

:not(:fullscreen) body {
  background-color: gold;
}

:not(:fullscreen) p {
  background-color: orange;
}

div {
  background-color: blue;
}

:fullscreen div {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="if (document.fullscreenElement) {(document.exitFullscreen || document.webkitExitFullscreen).call(document)}
   else {var elem = document.documentElement; (elem.requestFullscreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen).call(elem)}">toggle fullscreen</button>

<p>
  Negating fullscreen works for body but not for div. In fullscreen mode body turns white, but div stays orange.
</p>


<div>
  A work around.
</div>
```

(Running the snippet here, throws `Fullscreen request denied`. Thus use jsfiddle link above.)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a simple workaround (tested on Chrome, Edge, Firefox):

```css
html:not(:fullscreen) p {
    background-color: orange;
}
```